# How to plus 1 all numbers in a string within a certain range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an app with quiz questions and formulas. With a formula you can add up multiple quiz question scores with variables, for example `*|q1_score|* + *|q2_score|* + *|q3_score|* + *|q4_score|*`

When a quiz question is moved, I want to update numbers of the variables in the string that lie within a certain range.

Let's say quiz question 4 was moved to place 2, then I want to update that formula string to `*|q2_score|* + *|q1_score|* + *|q3_score|* + *|q4_score|*`

For now I have

```
const string = `*|q1_score|* + *|q2_score|* + *|q3_score|* +  *|q4_score|*`;

// Update actual quiz question that was moved
const originalOrder = 4;
const newOrder = 2;
const regex = new RegExp(`\\*\\|q${originalOrder}`, "g");
let newFormula = string.replace(regex, `*|q${newOrder}_`);

// Update all quiz questions with number after newOrder
const range = '3-4';
const regex2 = new RegExp(`\\*\\|q[${range}]`, "g");
let newFormula2 = string.replace(regex2, '*|q' + parseInt(p.match(/\d+/g) + 1) + '_'); // not sure what to put as 2nd param here
```

Basically I want to do +1 to all numbers in the string that were detected by regex `\\*\\|q[2-4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```js
const add = (match, group) => match.replace(new RegExp(group), parseInt(group)+1)
const input = `*|q1_score|* + *|q2_score|* + *|q3_score|* + *|q4_score|*`
const result = input.replace(/q([0-9])+_score/g, add)

console.log(result);
```

Put I guess a better solution would be not to hold your whole state in a string but in a structure (e.g. an array of strings or objects)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!